# Missing Return Statement

Tags: java, swing

i am attempting to take the value of a textfield and make apply it to a method in order to search a textfile for that value. But in my method i am shown a Missing Return Value error and cannot seem to make it work. below is my code:

```
        submitsearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

           whatToSearch = searchfield.getText();
                result = SearchString(whatToSearch);




        }
    });
}

 public String SearchString(String result)
 {
    String input;

    try{
        String details, id, line;
        int count;
        Scanner housenumber = new Scanner(new File("writeto.txt"));
        while(housenumber.hasNext())
        {
            id = housenumber.next();
            line = housenumber.nextLine();
            {

                if(!housenumber.hasNext())
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Properties with this criteria");
            }

            if(result.equals(id));
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,id + line );
            }

        }
   }

   catch(IOException e)
   {
        System.out.print("File failure");
      }
   }
}
```

Addendum:

In SearchString i am hoping to search my textfile for the value entered in my textfield display it in a JOptionPane. Although i now have the return statement when i click search i am shown all of the records in JOptionPanes one by one regardless of whether they match my search

Comment: Your `SearchString` method does not `return` a value anywhere, yet you've specified that it should return a `String`.

Comment: The real problem is that it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish in `SearchString`.  Maybe if you describe the input and desired results you can get a helpful answer.

Comment: In SearchString i am hoping to search my textfile for the value entered in my textfield display it in a JOptionPane. Although i now have the return statement when i click search i am shown all of the records in JOptionPanes one by one regardless of whether they match my search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `return null;` after catch block.

The method signature says that it returns a String. That implies no matter what flow your code takes, the method should return a value. But when an exception happens, there is no return. Hence you must specify a return value in the case when an exception happens

Answer (score 6):

You have declared the function with a return type of `String`, so it must return a `String` on all code paths. If you don't need it to return anything, use `void` instead.

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize the **all code paths** part here.  Because you have a try-catch structure and don't throw an exception in the catch block, that is considered a different path.  When you add your return statement, either place it outside of the try-catch blocks (preferred) or if you put a return in your try block, you'll need one in your catch block too.