# Java - Missing return statement

Tags: java

I get an error - "missing return statement" - on line 26, which in this case is the last curly bracket in the code. I know that it literally means that I have to return somewhere in the method (can you call it function?), but I'm not sure where - nor why.  Here's the code:

```
public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {

    Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap();

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("money.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);


    try{
        while (br.ready()){
            String str = br.readLine();
            String[] list = str.split(" ");
            System.out.println(list);               
        }
    }   catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("Error - IOException!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You get the error "missing return statement" because there is missing return statement.. Really.

Comment: You should get some tutorial before posting question here!

Comment: make it void instead of String[] (before function name) or just return list

Comment: If you don't need the return, you can change public String[] OpenFile() to public void OpenFile()

Comment: Use Eclipse or any other IDE. it will add it for you. Good going. Kudos

Comment: should put it where you want it to return - so I presume after executing all the code ;)
it should be inside the method scope though, so before the last '}'

Comment: I would rather not "bare with you".

Comment: As he mentioned "I'm a beginner at Java - so bare with me" So All below For You. By the way where is your money.txt ;)

Comment: @Messi1987 How do the contents of that file matter to this question **at all**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Return Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244258/missing-return-statement)

Answer (score 5):

Ok first of all please note that this is not really a beginners forum for learning any programming language. You will find it very hard to get a very basic question answered here without approximately 20 people pointing you in the direction of Google (myself included)

That being said please look for [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), beginners guides, or simply [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). The answer will almost everytime jump you straight in the face since there is just so much material on the java programming language

Stackoverflow is much more a question and answer site for more abstract problems, never-seen-before issues and tricky nuts for experts - all things that are likely to cater to a *general* audience and to help *many* people, not just yourself. Admittedly you posed your question quite nicely and formatted it well, so kudos to you and welcome to the site

As for this very specific problem you have the following options:

**Declare a void return type**

```
public void openFile() throws Exception {

}
```

**Return a preliminary `null` until you're sure what to return**

```
public String[] openFile() throws Exception {
    return null;
}
```

(But make sure that the calling entity knows what's coming back ;))

**Return some valid data to the entity that called the method**

```
public String[] openFile() throws Exception {
    String[] myArray = new String[5];
    return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to print the file as you are doing right now, change the return type to `void` as follows:

```
public void OpenFile() throws IOException {
```

Otherwise, since you are just opening and reading in a text file, you might want another `String` variable that you append the file's lines to and then return, as opposed to a `String[]`. Maybe something like this:

```
public String openFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

    String output = "";
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    try {
        while (br.ready()) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            output += line + "\n";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error - IOException!");
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that at all - silly mistake by me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
public String[] OpenFile() // expected return type is String array
```

But you didn't return that from your method.

If you don't want to return that change your method return type to `void`(no return)

```
public void OpenFile() throws IOException {

}
```

Or if you want to return as expected use

```
public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {

 String[] arr=new String[5];

 // implementation

 return arr;
```

}